# How to store hierarchy information in a nested structure

Tags: python, json, dictionary, text-files, file-conversion

Hope you all are doing great!

The below is an extract from a document into a .TXT file.
I wish to read the text file with the below contents:

```
1 Main Heading 1
1.1 Sub-heading 1
1.2 Sub-heading 2
2 Main Heading 2
2.1 Sub-heading 1
2.1.1 Sub-Sub-heading 1
2.1.2 Sub-Sub-heading 2
```

Upon reading, I want to DYNAMICALLY store it into a Python dictionary i.e. Nested lists like below:

```
{"file name": { "Main Heading 1": { "Sub-heading 1" : [], "Sub-heading 2" : [] }},
              { "Main Heading 2": { "Sub-heading 1": [ "Sub-Sub-heading 1", "Sub-Sub-heading 2" ] } } }
```

Above is not a fixed structure and can be dynamic with different files and I shall be further automating the process in a loop.
I am new to nested dictionary and am stuck with the ".txt file -> JSON" conversion stage. Any help on this regard would be very helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: Is it going to be always up to 3 levels? Also your structure is inconsistent - why when there is no sub-sub-heading, the sub-heading is in list, not dict with empty lists for sub-sub-headings?

Comment: 1. Max upto 3 levels, yes. 2. The structure you suggested will also work for me.. have edited the same in the question. Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

toc = """1 Main Heading 1
1.1 Sub-heading 1
1.2 Sub-heading 2
2 Main Heading 2
2.1 Sub-heading 1
2.1.1 Sub-Sub-heading 1
2.1.2 Sub-Sub-heading 2"""

myfile = 'myfile'

data = {myfile:{}}
for line in toc.splitlines():
    levels, title = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
    levels = levels.rstrip('.').split('.')
    if len(levels) == 1:
        heading = title
        data[myfile][heading] = {}
    elif len(levels) == 2:
        sub_heading = title
        data[myfile][heading][sub_heading] = []
    if len(levels) == 3:
        data[myfile][heading][sub_heading].append(title)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

output

```
{
    "myfile": {
        "Main Heading 1": {
            "Sub-heading 1": [],
            "Sub-heading 2": []
        },
        "Main Heading 2": {
            "Sub-heading 1": [
                "Sub-Sub-heading 1",
                "Sub-Sub-heading 2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean and brilliant code, mate. Worked like a charm!
This works for all except when the heading number end with a fullstop i.e. "1. XYZ", "2.1. ABC", which I tried to remove using replace() but didn't work without affecting other fullstops. Any suggestions?
Also, is there a way to handle cases where there are jumps like 1 to 1.1.1 instead of 1 to 1.1 and then 1.1.1

Comment: you can always .rstrip('.')` to remove trailing dot if present. I edited my answer

Comment: There is always a way to handle different cases, but what you describe 1 -> 1.1.1 doesn't make sense. It suggest incorrect structure

Comment: Thanks, rstrip worked. Regarding 1 -> 1.1.1, I know it's illogical but unfortunately the text output is from OCR'd PDF documents. Will need to handle it by editing 1.1.1 to 1.1 somehow - but not sure how comparing two lines in same txt works considering we are parsing file line by line.